# Compiling and running ApiDemos

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to compile Google's ApiDemos that come with the Android SDK.
But I just CANT GET IT TO RUN! It makes me crazy already!!

When I create a new project in Eclipse based on the sample (target 1.5 or 1.6) and try to compile and run, I get almost a thousand errors. Not what I'd expect from a tutorial app!

```
Description Resource Path Location Type
IRemoteService cannot be resolved RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 84 Java Problem
IRemoteService cannot be resolved to a type RemoteService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 92 Java Problem
IRemoteService cannot be resolved to a type RemoteService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 104 Java Problem
IRemoteService cannot be resolved to a type RemoteService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 104 Java Problem
IRemoteService cannot be resolved to a type RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 41 Java Problem
IRemoteService cannot be resolved to a type RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 84 Java Problem
IRemoteService cannot be resolved to a type RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 91 Java Problem
IRemoteService cannot be resolved to a type RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 107 Java Problem
IRemoteService cannot be resolved to a type RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 141 Java Problem
IRemoteService cannot be resolved to a type RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 155 Java Problem
IRemoteService cannot be resolved to a type RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 157 Java Problem
IRemoteServiceCallback cannot be resolved to a type RemoteService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 51 Java Problem
IRemoteServiceCallback cannot be resolved to a type RemoteService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 52 Java Problem
IRemoteServiceCallback cannot be resolved to a type RemoteService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 79 Java Problem
IRemoteServiceCallback cannot be resolved to a type RemoteService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 105 Java Problem
IRemoteServiceCallback cannot be resolved to a type RemoteService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 106 Java Problem
IRemoteServiceCallback cannot be resolved to a type RemoteService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 108 Java Problem
IRemoteServiceCallback cannot be resolved to a type RemoteService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 109 Java Problem
IRemoteServiceCallback cannot be resolved to a type RemoteService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 142 Java Problem
IRemoteServiceCallback cannot be resolved to a type RemoteService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 145 Java Problem
IRemoteServiceCallback cannot be resolved to a type RemoteService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 151 Java Problem
IRemoteServiceCallback cannot be resolved to a type RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 91 Java Problem
IRemoteServiceCallback cannot be resolved to a type RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 157 Java Problem
IRemoteServiceCallback cannot be resolved to a type RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 212 Java Problem
IRemoteServiceCallback cannot be resolved to a type RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 212 Java Problem
ISecondary cannot be resolved RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 125 Java Problem
ISecondary cannot be resolved to a type RemoteService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 95 Java Problem
ISecondary cannot be resolved to a type RemoteService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 116 Java Problem
ISecondary cannot be resolved to a type RemoteService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 116 Java Problem
ISecondary cannot be resolved to a type RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 43 Java Problem
ISecondary cannot be resolved to a type RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 125 Java Problem
ISecondary cannot be resolved to a type RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 130 Java Problem
ISecondary cannot be resolved to a type RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 143 Java Problem
ISecondary cannot be resolved to a type RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 179 Java Problem
ISecondary cannot be resolved to a type RemoteServiceBinding.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 181 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AdvancedPreferences.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 58 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlarmController.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 73 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlarmController.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 76 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlarmController.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 78 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlarmController.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 80 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlarmController.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 108 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlarmController.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 140 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlarmController.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 162 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlarmService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 52 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlarmService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 55 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlarmService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 57 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlarmService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 72 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlarmService.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 84 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlarmService_Service.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 62 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlarmService_Service.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 65 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlarmService_Service.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 100 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlarmService_Service.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 103 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlarmService_Service.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 111 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlarmService_Service.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 116 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 75 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 76 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 77 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 83 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 92 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 93 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 94 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 95 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 101 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 107 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 116 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 117 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 121 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 130 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 131 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 134 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 140 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 149 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 150 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 151 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 157 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 163 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 172 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 173 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 174 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 183 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 189 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 199 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 201 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 202 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 204 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 210 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 230 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 233 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 241 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 250 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 258 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 269 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 277 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app line 285 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AlphaBitmap.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics line 67 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable AnimateDrawables.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics line 46 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable Animation1.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view line 34 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable Animation1.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view line 36 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable Animation1.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view line 41 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable Animation1.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view line 42 Java Problem

...and 841 more.
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android APIDemos Compile Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346662/android-apidemos-compile-errors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had the same thing, and found that buried in the massive list of errors, there were some xml parsing errors for strings.xml. There are 4 unescaped single quotes in the text which eclipse doesn't like. The problem strings are "I'm off!" "I'm on!", and "you'll" and "you're" in the big block of text starting "The Android platform is a software stack...". If you escape these by putting \ in front of each apostrophe, all the errors magically disappear :)

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem.

I found that eclipse had automatically targeted Android 1.6. But the API demo was from the 4.4.2 sdk.

I changed the 'project build target' to Android 4.4.2 in the project properties and it compiled and ran fine.

Comment: Same here.  Note that some may need to do a forced clean after changing the target.

Comment: Change it to 4.4.2 for the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems at first. This worked for me, using API 15:

1. First remove the samples and re-add it using the SDK manager, just to be sure you're starting clean.
2. Import/Android/Existing Android Code into Workspace
3. For root directory provide the path to ApiDemos, like: /opt/android-sdks/samples/android-15/ApiDemos
4. Click refresh, and the ApiDemos package should show up. Select it and finish.

I think this is tricky to setup because initial attempts produce eclipse files within the file structure, and subsequent attempts fail because eclipse tries to use those files again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try importing the API Demo project from File->Import then show the directory of the API Demo folder.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I know what you mean... I can't import the ApiDemos project, because there's no project available, it's just a directory with the dirs/files (assets, res, src, tests, AndroidManifest.xml, default.properties). I create the project by picking File->New->Project >> Anroid Project >> Create project from existing sample.

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting the latest SDK version, rather than 1.5 or 1.6.

Comment: But shouldn't the ApiDemos sample from the /platforms/android-4/samples work fine when trying to run on a 1.6 emulator? (my pda still runs the 1.6 OS so I was aiming to get it running on such device)

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same issue.  I am running MyEclipse 8.0. When you look at these errors you see that you need to bring in an IRemoteService class.  I assumed this means the com.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.IRemoteService interface. I tried to load the ecf project but there are issues with that.  If anyone has successfully integrated ECF into their Eclipse let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set properties>android to the correct build target -- then clean and retry.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and I found that it was because I had imported the project into an Eclipse workspace that I already had other projects open in. I selected those projects in the "Package Explorer" pane and then selected Project->Close Project. I did that for each other project in the workspace leaving only the ApiDemos project open. Then I did a clean build and it was successful. (with 293 warnings - yikes).

Answer (score 0):

I encounter similar issues in Android Studio with Gradle build system.
And my reason is not complie aidl files correctly, for example `IRemoteService` is defined in *IRemoteService.aidl* actually. So my solution is add sourceSets configuration in **build.gradle** as follow:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        dirs.each { dir ->
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs "src"
            res.srcDirs "res"
            aidl.srcDirs "src"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and this is my solution.

1. Uncheck "Build automatically" in the menu "project"
2. Select "Clean" from menu "project".
3. Select "Clean projects selected below" and check "ApiDemos".
4. Check "Start a build immediatly", "Build only the selected projects"

Then it compiles as it should (at least for me).

After this you can check "Build automatically" in the menu "project" again.

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9670606/785827 .
Hope it helps!

Best regards from germany.