# Android source code import in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have downloaded the android source code from the android master branch. I followed the procedure given on the website to build it. When I run it from terminal everything builds fine without errors. When I followed the procedure to import this I eclipse it throws me about 2000 errors
the errors basically include 
`IRemoteService cannot be resolved` and 
`IRemoteServiceCallback cannot be resolved.` 
Has anyone encountered the same issues ?

Comment: It seems you are missing jars in classpath.

Comment: There are no errors shown by eclipse in the buildpath. i followed the instructions given on android website which says to copy the class path file from a subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

This error has been proposed before on StackOverflow - try this thread and see if it helps:

[Compiling and running ApiDemos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298155/compiling-and-running-apidemos)

Otherwise, it would be helpful to see your code or perhaps a link to the site you are using to try to reproduce the error and provide more specific answers. My first thoughts were that your build-path had some issues in your project properties that it is not finding the appropriate libraries.

Comment: i am not using android SDK. I am building android from the source.